# Why is my header not responding in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

MY `http`, `header`, `RequestOption` are not working properly in the API. I'm using Angular 7.1. I have tried every formula but nothing is happening.

**I have this error:**

> token is not passing in header

**I am using this code:**

```js
import { Http,RequestOptions,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UrlrequestService {
    public headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    API:any = "http://api-url";
    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    get(url) {  
        this.headers.set('Authorization','Token  '+localStorage.getItem('token'))
        let options = { headers: this.headers };
        console.log(options)
        return this.http.get(this.API+url,options);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: token is not passing in header

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159085/8718377 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158945/8718377

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 7, you should import `HttpClient` and `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http`. Moreover, you should use `Bearer` to pass the token.
Try something like that:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

// ...

httpOptions;
api_path:any = "http://api-url";

constructor(public http: Http) {}


// ...
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
};
```

Comment: HttpHeader is not assignable to parameter

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass HTTP Headers, remember the tokens are of type `Bearer`.So the authorization header line should be like this:

```
this.headers.set('Authorization','Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

Comment: HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error
Type Status Report

Message Token is missing

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Please try clearing you cache and try again. `Bearer` is the only mistake I found in your code. When i coded with `Token` in my codes, I also got 401 error but when i used `Bearer`, it worked!

Comment: You got 401 that's ok but i got 500 tomcat server error

Comment: no that was when i used `Token` but when I used `Bearer` it worked fine! Seems there is server error

Comment: Using Postman its working fine when i am using 'Token' in Authorization. The problem is in Api it can't able to set headers